# Clang check for deleted assignment operator + declaration handling

Tags: c++, clang, obfuscation, variable-declaration

I'm trying to do automated control flow flattening  of C++ code via source-to-source transformation using the AST in clang. This means I change the control flow of a function into one big switch statement that handles all basic blocks.

This also means, that I need all variable declarations in the beginning of the function (before the switch statement, otherwise the scope would be different). When a variable is initiated during declaration, the declaration must be put to the front and the initialization stays the same.

```
...
A a = b;
return a;
```

is transformed to

```
A a; // at the beginning
...
a = b; //at the point of a's declaration
return a;
```

So far this works, wouldn't there be some problems with C++: Type `class A` could have e.g. no default constructor. Or, even worse, a deleted copy assignment operator. This would forbid me to initiate the variable after the declaration with another instantiation of `class A`.

So this finally brings me to my question: **is there a way in clang to check if a type is a class with a deleted copy assignment operator, so that I can handle it differently?** I couldn't find any method in `clang::Type` or `clang::QualType`.

Maybe you have also a better idea of **how to handle it differently**, my approach would be (with the example above):

```
A *a1; // at the beginning
...
A a = b; //at the point of a's declaration
a1 = &a;
return *(a1); // replace a at every occurrence with *(a1)
```

This means I need for every variable declaration an additional pointer and that is why I only want to use this if necessary.

Comment: Initialization isn't the only problem. You're also messing with destruction. Potentially braking RAII. (Think about lock guards. You can't move those around, neither their initialization nor their destruction.) Also, even if you can do your first proposed transform, nothing guarantees that it will have the same effects as the original code.

Comment: Do you have any solution for the problem? Would my approach with the additional pointer help?

Comment: I don't understand how your alternate approach would help you. The `a1` in your code is useless, you have `a` in scope already.

Comment: Well I don't have it in scope anymore after flattening. My return statement would be in a different switch case than the declaration of a.

Comment: But if you "change scopes" between `a1 = &a` and `*a1`, `a` will have had its lifetime ended and `a1` is now pointing to garbage.

Comment: Oh damn it, your right ... :/ any better solution?

Comment: Not really. You need to model object creation/destruction as part of the flow. Prob need to allocate raw bytes at the start and use placement new and manual destructor calls to match the original semantics.

Comment: @Mat My thought was that you could flatten *control flow* without flattening blocks. You can have brace-enclosed blocks without any control flow surrounding them, to model creation/destruction as `case SomeCondition: doThing(); {A a = b; doSomethingWith(a);} doOtherThing();`.